# My matches rule codeigniter doesn't work with the Strings I entered

Tags: codeigniter

In my controller I have

```
array(array('field' => 'City', 'label' => 'City', 'rules' => 'required|matches[form_"Limerick"]', 'errors' => array('required' => '%s is a mandatory field', 'matches' => '%s must be either Cork, Limerick or Galway')),
```

For some reason when I enter those strings it still pops an error saying it must be one of those strings.
I am totally new to codeigniter doing it in college.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be

```
array(array('field' => 'City', 'label' => 'City', 'rules' => 'required|matches[form_Limerick]', 'errors' => array('required' => '%s is a mandatory field', 'matches' => '%s must be either Cork, Limerick or Galway')),
```

use `form_Limerick` instead of  `form_"Limerick"`
remove double inverted from string Limerick...

or let me know If you till getting error.
Thanks!